# Problem with links once in portfolio item

Tags: menus, permalinks, navigation, links

Hope someone could help me.

Link problem:

This is my Homepage URL: https://epix.com.mx 
Portfolio onepage link: https://epix.com.mx/#Projects 
Portfolio item link: https://epix.com.mx/?portfolio=huitzilin (permalink), once here if I want to go back to my homepage using the same menu, the link is wrong:
https://epix.com.mx/?portfolio=huitzilin#Home
correct one would be:
https://epix.com.mx/#Home

Why Is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your `Appearance > Menus` Select activated Menu & check its links by clicking on the name tab, you are probably using `#Home` link instead of using a full url of that specific page.

Example:

Home Url should be: `https://epix.com.mx`

You might be using: `#Home`

**Update:** If your website has more than one page/s than you should create separate navigation menus.

Separate menu for homepage & Separate menu for other page/s this way you can avoid css style conflicts. You should have an option to use separate menu for specific Page. You can use #home navigation as your homepage menu & other full link navigation for the rest of the pages.

Comment: Thanks @Arsalan, I appretiate your help.
The problem is that I have a onepage website and menu links are following this format: #about #projects #testimonials #contact since it navigates in the same page.

For the portfolio items WP sends me to a different link (which changes to another page) and there is when it doesn't work anymore>

Righ now I changed the "About" link on the menu to https://epix.com.mx/About but it shows it in red since n the homepage is an active link and also doesn't work that way.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ITCilRY.png

Comment: Yes Obviously, coz that's the active link. 
Simply you need another Navigation bar for the page which has scroll sections, (like your homepage) where you can only put sections ids like #About #Contact etc & full links on another Nav bar. That's exactly what's happening in your Demo theme as well. Check to see if there are 2 or more menus created in your Menu list

Comment: @EpixMedia i just updated my answer following your concern.

Comment: I appreciate your help, you're absolutely right, I had the other menu disabled. Right now I enabled it and apply proper links.. now it works perfectly
THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Glad it helped :)